# Problem with proxy after installing tor

Tags: proxy, tor, socks5

Recently I installed Tor on my ubuntu(17.10) and then I figured it out that Tor has set to the wide computer's internet.
HTTP = 127.0.0.1:8118
SOCKS = 127.0.0.1:9050
When I disable the proxy in setting, I can't open any web page or anything. Can you guys help me how to get through this? I want to disable it.